# jquery ui alternative

Tags: css, jquery

jquery ui "Draggable", "Droppable", "Autocomplete", "Datepicker", "Dialog" I use widgets intensively in my project.

But I'm not happy with jquery ui css no mobile compatibility.

I have over 400+ pages loaded with my project.

I couldn't decide how to switch to a mobile compatible and fast ui framework.

Which framework should I use and how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 400 pages already coded, you have a large effort on your hands to change to something else.

Switching to a modern framework or library like React, Angular, or Vue will be entering a large re-write effort.   What you don't want to do is use both (eg, react and jquery) if you can avoid it.  The conflicts and methodologies don't lend themselves to working nice together.

What is your re-write appetite?  Timeline? budget concerns? etc.  Weigh those out.

If the answer is that it's too much/too hard to switch, it may be best to consider adapting to show your mobile site with less 'coolness'.  Follow the design principles of [graceful degradation](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Graceful_degradation_versus_progressive_enhancement).